# Error when trying to add item and value to dropdownlist in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, dropdownbox

I am trying to add an item and value to an asp.net dropdownlist control.

```
arrEmpName = HttpContext.Current.Session["EmployeeName"].ToString();
arrEmpID = HttpContext.Current.Session["EmpID"].ToString();
char[] separator = new char[] { ',' };

string[] sEmployeeName = arrEmployeeName.Split(separator);
string[] sEmpID = arrEmpID.Split(separator);

foreach (string s in sEmployeeName)
{
    ddlEmp.Items.Add(new ListItem(sEmployeeName, sEmpID));
}
```

I get two error messages :

> 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListItem.ListItem(string, string)' has some
>   invalid arguments

and

> ```
> Argument 1: cannot convert from 'string[]' to 'string'
> ```

Any ideas what the issue(s) would be ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're trying to add the arrays as a whole to the ListItem value. I suspect they're supposed to be linked:

```
string[] sEmployeeName = arrEmployeeName.Split(separator);
string[] sEmpID = arrEmpID.Split(separator);

for (int i = 0; i < sEmployeeName.Length; i++)
{
    ddlEmp.Items.Add(new ListItem(sEmployeeName[i], sEmpID[i]));
}
```

You may also want to consider checking that they're the same length:

```
if (sEmployeeName.Length != sEmpID.Length)
    throw new Exception("Number of employee names does not match the number of IDs!");
```

EDIT: Could throw in some Linq if you want though not really necessary:

```
var employees = Enumerable.Zip(arrEmployeeName.Split(separator), arrEmpID.Split(separator), (name, id) => new { Name = name, ID = id } );
foreach(var employee in employees)
{
    ddlEmp.Items.Add(new ListItem(employee.Name, employee.ID));
}
```

Comment: coulda sworn I had already tried that... but that works. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're arrays are always equal length and match one to one (between a name and id):

```
for (int i = 0; i < sEmployeeName.Length; ++i)
{
    var employeeName = sEmployeeName[i];
    var employeeId = sEmpID[i];

    ddlEmp.Items.Add(new ListItem(employeeName, employeeId));
}
```

You were sending the `arrays` in.